# What is the difference between read file through csv and pipe reading in julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

What is the difference between:

```
using CSV;

df = CSV.read("data.csv");
```

and

```
df = CSV.read("data.csv") |> DataFrame;
```

I mean, in the first case `df` is read as DataFrame, what the need for the pipe in the second case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = CSV.read("data.csv");
```

is currently a shorthand for:

```
df = CSV.read("data.csv", DataFrame);
```

(in the future the former will be disallowed most likely)

I am not sure where you have seen:

```
df = CSV.read("data.csv") |> DataFrame;
```

as this is not needed. You create an unnecessary additional copy of your data frame.

Probably you meant:

```
df = CSV.File("data.csv") |> DataFrame;
```

which is a low-level API of CSV.jl.

In short. It is recommended to use:

```
df = CSV.read("data.csv", DataFrame);
```

Comment: argh sniped. Can't one take two minutes writing a response these days without getting passed on the right? :-D :-D

Comment: Ah - sorry. I just done my morning house duties and saw that the question was unanswered for several hours :).

Answer (score 2):

It's just for explicitness. `CSV.read("data.csv") |> DataFrame` is identical to `DataFrame(CSV.read("data.csv"))`, which in principle guarantees that you'll end up with a DataFrame even if CSV changes their output format at some point in the future.
Note that it would be more ideomatic to write `CSV.File("data.csv") |> DataFrame`, and this makes it easy to change the output format at any time in the future.

Comment: Agreed. As I have commended in my answer the target API in CSV.jl is `CSV.read("source_file", SinkType)`, so that you can efficiently materialize to whatever target table type you prefer.

Comment: `CSV.File` does materialize the data in memory. The difference is that it doesn't return a  `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks Milan, edited my answer. I'm quite surprised by this actually.